# Are local classes that are queried from database, causes race condition?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```java
public class A { 
    String name = "foo";
}

@Service
public class B {
    
    private final Repository repo;
    
    public void someMethod(){
        A a = repo.findByName("foo");
        a.name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        repo.save(a);
    }
}
```

Imagine that 2 thread executed someMethod at the same time. Especially in jpa hibernate implementation.

My opinion is there is a race condition.

First and second threads are obtained same object with name foo. If i am not wrong, without optimistic lock there will be error in this scenario.

Also optimistic lock throws exception so do i need to use pessimistic lock to work correctly?

Also if i open second level cache with distributed in memory cache(Redis, hazelcast), what will happen?

It is a IOT project and million devices are calling this api and service.
Do i need to approach with eventual consistency?

Comment: You're using multithreading terminology to describe database transactions, which is confusing. It's not a race condition, it's just a transaction which may fail with optimistic locking. You would then need to handle it somehow (such as retrying the failed transaction). You *can* use pessimistic locking, but it's possible that optimistic locking is still better, unless the transactions fail too often.

Comment: How about if i open second level cache to cache queries? Is it possible to reduce select query performance? But it is frequently changing. I need to implement cache which handles specific features. Also it is micro service architecture so i cant really rely on total transaction. Even if i use saga pattern to keep transaction in check. Still too much thing to do :).

Comment: I guess i need to do a Load test. I can handle with Jmeter with cloud computers. (Aws or azure maybe)

Comment: I guess, maybe, possibly. Time will tell, it's up to you.